# Push-Notification works on develpoment but not on production

Tags: iphone, app-store, push-notification

So we have a problem with our app. We put push-notification in, and it works flawlessly in development. Then, once we got on the app store push no longer works. By looking at our server logs it looks like the the registration call is failing and not getting a device token.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Cheers,

Answer (score 3):

Did you create a production push notification SSL certificate?  This is most frequently the cause.  Applications signed with a development provisioning profile will not work with a production push SSL cert and applications signed with a distribution provisioning profile will not work with a development push cert.

Also, you can create an ad-hoc distribution cert and use this to test your distribution provisioning profile.  Since you can't run the build you send to Apple for distribution, I'd strongly encourage you to make an ad-hoc distribution build and confirm that push notifications work in that installation.